# List of (date, day_of_week) tuples

Tags: python, list, datetime, syntax

I know that what I'm trying to do is possible.  I just haven't been able to figure it out.  I'm hoping that someone who has more experience working with dates in python can help me out.

I am attempting to create a list of a date range, where each element in my list consists of a date and which day of the week that date represents.  Here is what I have so far.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%b %d, %Y"
a = datetime.strptime('Feb 16, 2013', date_format)
b = datetime.strptime('Aug 11, 2013', date_format)
delta = b - a
delta = delta.days # that's it

print a
print b

base = a    

dateList = [ base + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0,delta) ]

print dateList
```

As you can see I don't have anything in for the day of the week -- so it's not even the correct tuple-form expression. I've found and read what I believe is [the correct documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for day of week (see date.weekday()), but I just can't seem to get it working. Perhaps it's because I don't understand objects well enough.

Also I don't know how to alter the format that timedelta returns -- viz., datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 25, 0, 0) -- as I don't need the words datetime.datetime to precede my tuples once I'm creating them.

I welcome any comment or feedback about how to do what I'm attempting to do -- assuming it's possible.  Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datetime` object itself has a `.weekday()` attribute. You can add these in a separate loop:

```
dateList = [(d, d.weekday()) for d in dateList]
```

For your example code, that gives:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 16, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 17, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 18, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 19, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 20, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 21, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 22, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 23, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 24, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 25, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 26, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 27, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 1, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 2, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 3, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 4, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 5, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 6, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 7, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 8, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 9, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 10, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 11, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 12, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 13, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 14, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 15, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 16, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 17, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 18, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 19, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 20, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 21, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 22, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 23, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 24, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 25, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 26, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 27, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 28, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 29, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 30, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 1, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 2, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 3, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 5, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 6, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 7, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 8, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 9, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 10, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 11, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 12, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 13, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 14, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 15, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 16, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 17, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 18, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 19, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 20, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 21, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 22, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 23, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 24, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 25, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 26, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 27, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 28, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 29, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 1, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 2, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 3, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 4, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 5, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 6, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 7, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 8, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 9, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 10, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 11, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 12, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 13, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 14, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 15, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 16, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 17, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 18, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 19, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 20, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 21, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 22, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 23, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 24, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 25, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 26, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 27, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 28, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 29, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 30, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 31, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 1, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 2, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 3, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 5, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 6, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 7, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 8, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 9, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 10, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 11, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 12, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 13, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 14, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 15, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 16, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 17, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 18, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 19, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 20, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 21, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 22, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 23, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 24, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 25, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 27, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 28, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 29, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 30, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 1, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 2, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 3, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 4, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 5, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 6, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 7, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 8, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 9, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 10, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 11, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 12, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 13, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 14, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 15, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 16, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 17, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 18, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 19, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 20, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 21, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 22, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 23, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 24, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 25, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 26, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 28, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 29, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 30, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 31, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 1, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 2, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 3, 0, 0), 5), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 4, 0, 0), 6), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 5, 0, 0), 0), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 6, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 7, 0, 0), 2), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 8, 0, 0), 3), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 9, 0, 0), 4), (datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 10, 0, 0), 5)]
```

You can combine it with your existing list comprehension by creating an extra nested loop with one element:

```
dateList = [(d, d.weekday()) for x in range(0,delta) for d in [base + timedelta(days=x)]]
```

Comment: Incredible.  I spent hours reading and applying different solutions.  Granted I suck, but this is really cool.  Thank you, sir.